# View cart location on a responsive e-commerce site 'on mobile'

Tags: mobile, e-commerce

Would it be better to have the view cart button or indicator showing in the header area?  Or would you hide it away in a drop down or menu area? Has anyone got any good and bad points on this... or just some general ideas on where to put the best place to put a cart area on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view cart action is probably the second most important action on the product listing part of the site (The first is "add to bag"). Every single person who wants to use the site for its primary purpose (buying things) needs to click that button.

Hiding the interaction behind a drop-down menu is doing a disservice both to the users who want to check out and the business that wants to sell things.

The conventional place to put it is in the top right corner of the screen. In this case, following the convention aids discoverability, and prevents user frustration.

I'd think very carefully before you decide to hide that button.

Answer (score 1):

I have mine fixed to the bottom right of the screen and my customers find it there quite easily.

I definitely use a bright color that is different than the rest of the user interface.

I would not hide it on any user interface, mobile or otherwise. That will only lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen on most websites, it is located in the top right corner with a different color than your other buttons. By hiding it inside a dropdown or placing it on a hard to find location, you risk the user navigating away from the web page if they don't find it. Most users don't go around looking for things, so one must present them with the best layout where everything is easily accessible.

In this certain example, its right below the header, but easily identified by the yellow color.

You can also take a look at location of this website's Ask Question button.

[image: Sample]